# Mandelbrot Change from One thread being used over and over to two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

ýSeen this code earlier and have been trying to improve it as I think it would work better with multiple threads instead of constantly using the one and I reckon conditional variables would improve as it would enable signaling between threads. I have cut a part of the code and put it in the bottom (therefore it is technically highlighted, ignore the rest expect for tracing variables) :

```
// Import things we need from the standard library

using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::complex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ofstream;

// Define the alias "the_clock" for the clock type we're going to use.
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock the_clock;

// The size of the image to generate.
const int WIDTH = 1920;
const int HEIGHT = 1080;

// The number of times to iterate before we assume that a point isn't in the
// Mandelbrot set.
// (You may need to turn this up if you zoom further into the set.)
const int MAX_ITERATIONS = 500;

// The image data.
// Each pixel is represented as 0xRRGGBB.
uint32_t image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];


// Write the image to a TGA file with the given name.
// Format specification: http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake3/TGA.txt
void write_tga(const char *filename)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename, ofstream::binary);

    uint8_t header[18] = {
        0, // no image ID
        0, // no colour map
        2, // uncompressed 24-bit image
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // empty colour map specification
        0, 0, // X origin
        0, 0, // Y origin
        WIDTH & 0xFF, (WIDTH >> 8) & 0xFF, // width
        HEIGHT & 0xFF, (HEIGHT >> 8) & 0xFF, // height
        24, // bits per pixel
        0, // image descriptor
    };
    outfile.write((const char *)header, 18);

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            uint8_t pixel[3] = {
                image[y][x] & 0xFF, // blue channel
                (image[y][x] >> 8) & 0xFF, // green channel
                (image[y][x] >> 16) & 0xFF, // red channel
            };
            outfile.write((const char *)pixel, 3);
        }
    }

    outfile.close();
    if (!outfile)
    {
        // An error has occurred at some point since we opened the file.
        cout << "Error writing to " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}


// Render the Mandelbrot set into the image array.
// The parameters specify the region on the complex plane to plot.
void compute_mandelbrot(const double left, const double right, const double top, const double bottom)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            // Work out the point in the complex plane that
            // corresponds to this pixel in the output image.
            complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
                top + (y * (bottom - top) / HEIGHT));

            // Start off z at (0, 0).
            complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);

            // Iterate z = z^2 + c until z moves more than 2 units
            // away from (0, 0), or we've iterated too many times.
            int iterations = 0;
            while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
            {
                z = (z * z) + c;

                ++iterations;
            }

            if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS)
            {
                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0x000000; // black
            }
            else
            {
                // z escaped within less than MAX_ITERATIONS
                // iterations. This point isn't in the set.
                image[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF; // white
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Processor logical cores: " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << endl;

    cout << "Please wait..." << endl;

    // Sequential implementation
    if(true)
    {
        cout << "Sequential code..." << endl;
        // Start timing
        the_clock::time_point start = the_clock::now();

        // This shows the whole set.
        compute_mandelbrot(-2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125);

        // This zooms in on an interesting bit of detail.
        //compute_mandelbrot(-0.751085, -0.734975, 0.118378, 0.134488);

        // Stop timing
        the_clock::time_point end = the_clock::now();

        // Compute the difference between the two times in milliseconds
        auto time_taken = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        cout << "Computing the Mandelbrot set took " << time_taken << " ms." << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Parallel implementation - method 1
    if(true)
    {
        cout << "Parallel using C++ threads - method 1..." << endl;

        // Test with various thread numbers
        for (int threads_count = 1; threads_count < 15; ++threads_count)
        {
            // Start timing
            const the_clock::time_point start = the_clock::now();

            // Threads vector
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;

            const int chunk_size = HEIGHT / threads_count;
            int y1 = 0;
            int y2 = chunk_size;
            for (int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
            {
                // Divide work into equal area chunks, then let each thread calculate its part
                y1 = i * chunk_size;
                y2 = y1 + chunk_size;
                if (y2 > HEIGHT) y2 = HEIGHT;

                // Start the thread - compute_mandelbrot takes area to be calculated by a given thread through [y1, y2)
                threads.push_back(std::thread([y1, y2](const double left, const double right, const double top, const double bottom) 
                {
                    for (int y = y1; y < y2; ++y)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
                        {
                            // Work out the point in the complex plane that
                            // corresponds to this pixel in the output image.
                            complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
                                top + (y * (bottom - top) / HEIGHT));

                            // Start off z at (0, 0).
                            complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);

                            // Iterate z = z^2 + c until z moves more than 2 units
                            // away from (0, 0), or we've iterated too many times.
                            int iterations = 0;
                            while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
                            {
                                z = (z * z) + c;

                                ++iterations;
                            }

                            if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS)
                            {
                                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                                image[y][x] = 0x000000; // black
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // z escaped within less than MAX_ITERATIONS
                                // iterations. This point isn't in the set.
                                image[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF; // white
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, -2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125));
            }

            //Join threads
            for (auto &t : threads)
                t.join();

            // Stop timing
            const the_clock::time_point end = the_clock::now();

            // Compute the difference between the two times in milliseconds
            const auto time_taken = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
            cout << "Threads: " << threads_count << ", time: " << time_taken << " ms." << endl;

        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Parallel implementation - method 2
    if (true)
    {
        cout << "Parallel using C++ threads - method 2..." << endl;

        // Test with various thread numbers
        for (int threads_count = 1; threads_count < 15; ++threads_count)
        {
            // Start timing
            const the_clock::time_point start = the_clock::now();

            // Indicates next chunk of work to be done
            // Using std::atomic allows synchronized access when checking the exit condition of the while loop in the thread function
            std::atomic<int> work_queue(0);

            // To allow synchronized read/write to work_queue
            // Used to prevent race condition between the threads when accessing work_queue
            // It is protecting work_queue to be accessed only by one of the threads at a time
            std::mutex queue_mutex;

            // Threads vector
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;

            //Lauch #parts threads
            for (int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
            {
                // Start the thread - work_queue points to the next chunk of data to be calculated
                threads.push_back(std::thread([&work_queue, &queue_mutex](const double left, const double right, const double top, const double bottom, const int height)
                {
                    // Our arbitrarily chosen chunk_size
                    // Smaller chunk_size allows for the work to be distributed more evenly amongst the threads, however this also increases
                    // thread synchronization overhead
                    static constexpr int chunk_size = 20;

                    // If nothing to be done, exit the thread
                    while (work_queue * chunk_size < height)
                    {
                        int part = 0;
                        {
                            // Lock our sychronization mutex
                            // This ensures that only one thread can read/write to the work_queue at the same time
                            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(queue_mutex);

                            // Take the next chunk of work to be done and increment the counter
                            part = work_queue++;

                            // Again, if nothing to be done, exit the thread
                            if (part >= height)
                                break;
                        }

                        for (int y = part * chunk_size; y < part * chunk_size + chunk_size && y < height; ++y)
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
                            {
                                // Work out the point in the complex plane that
                                // corresponds to this pixel in the output image.
                                complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
                                    top + (y * (bottom - top) / HEIGHT));

                                // Start off z at (0, 0).
                                complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);

                                // Iterate z = z^2 + c until z moves more than 2 units
                                // away from (0, 0), or we've iterated too many times.
                                int iterations = 0;
                                while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
                                {
                                    z = (z * z) + c;

                                    ++iterations;
                                }

                                if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS)
                                {
                                    // z didn't escape from the circle.
                                    // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                                    image[y][x] = 0x000000; // black
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // z escaped within less than MAX_ITERATIONS
                                    // iterations. This point isn't in the set.
                                    image[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF; // white
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, -2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125, HEIGHT));
            }

            //Join threads
            for (auto &t : threads)
                t.join();

            // Stop timing
            const the_clock::time_point end = the_clock::now();

            // Compute the difference between the two times in milliseconds
            const auto time_taken = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
            cout << "Threads: " << threads_count << ", time: " << time_taken << " ms." << endl;

        }
    }

    write_tga("output.tga");

    system("pause");

    return 0;
```

THIS IS THE MAIN PART THAT IS BEING EDITED

```
// Parallel implementation - method 2
if (true)
{
    cout << "Parallel using C++ threads - method 2..." << endl;

    // Test with various thread numbers
    for (int threads_count = 1; threads_count < 15; ++threads_count)
    {
        // Start timing
        const the_clock::time_point start = the_clock::now();

        // Indicates next chunk of work to be done
        // Using std::atomic allows synchronized access when checking the exit condition of the while loop in the thread function
        std::atomic<int> work_queue(0);

        // To allow synchronized read/write to work_queue
        // Used to prevent a race condition between the threads when accessing work_queue
        // It is protecting work_queue to be accessed only by one of the threads at a time
        std::mutex queue_mutex;

        // Threads vector
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        //Lauch #parts threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
        {
            // Start the thread - work_queue points to the next chunk of data to be calculated
            threads.push_back(std::thread([&work_queue, &queue_mutex](const double left, const double right, const double top, const double bottom, const int height)
            {
                // Our arbitrarily chosen chunk_size
                // Smaller chunk_size allows for the work to be distributed more evenly amongst the threads, however, this also increases
                // thread synchronization overhead
                static constexpr int chunk_size = 20;

                // If nothing to be done, exit the thread
                while (work_queue * chunk_size < height)
                {
                    int part = 0;
                    {
                        // Lock our sychronization mutex
                        // This ensures that only one thread can read/write to the work_queue at the same time
                        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(queue_mutex);

                        // Take the next chunk of work to be done and increment the counter
                        part = work_queue++;

                        // Again, if nothing to be done, exit the thread
                        if (part >= height)
                            break;
                    }

                    for (int y = part * chunk_size; y < part * chunk_size + chunk_size && y < height; ++y)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
                        {
                            // Work out the point in the complex plane that
                            // corresponds to this pixel in the output image.
                            complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
                                top + (y * (bottom - top) / HEIGHT));

                            // Start off z at (0, 0).
                            complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);

                            // Iterate z = z^2 + c until z moves more than 2 units
                            // away from (0, 0), or we've iterated too many times.
                            int iterations = 0;
                            while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
                            {
                                z = (z * z) + c;

                                ++iterations;
                            }

                            if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS)
                            {
                                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                                image[y][x] = 0x000000; // black
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // z escaped within less than MAX_ITERATIONS
                                // iterations. This point isn't in the set.
                                image[y][x] = 0xFFFFFF; // white
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, -2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125, HEIGHT));
        }

        //Join threads
        for (auto &t : threads)
            t.join();
```

I tried to map out how I would make it two threads as opposed to one. But can't even think as to where to put the conditional variable. This may not be what is usually on stack overflow but seriously stuck, not looking to get a rake of downvotes by a bunch of haters, just trying to solve this problem. How would you approach making the one thread into two and would you implement a conditional variable, excited to hear your peoples thoughts on this project

Comment: Every pixel in the image can be calculated independently of each other. I'd honestly just take the pixel index MOD 2 and calculate its color value on the thread whose index is equal to that resulting number.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good fit for [OpenMP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), which allows you to tell the compiler, by annotating the source code, which bits of any particular algorithm can be executed in parallel.

I believe most of the major compilers support it (you don't state your platform), including [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx).

Want to take that and run with it?  There are various sources of information on the web about this, including [this tutorial at openmp.org](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjEwbm6_YncAhXQmLQKHavWApMQFjABegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw2BMZ-x-dl68_2rW2LZevlD).